# VSCode debugger not stopping at breakpoint (with -g compilation)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

I have a C++ project that I am trying to debug with VSCode debugger, but it doesn't stop at breakpoints (at execution, breakpoints says "Module containing this breakpoint has not yet loaded or the breakpoint address could not be obtained."). Strangely, it does stop at entry if I use `"stopAtEntry": false` option in launch.json.

I tried to simplify my code as much as possible, but the problem is still present.
All the code is in a subfolder called "SRC/".

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
all: main

main: Main.cpp
    g++ Main.cpp -g -Wall -o main
```

tasks.json:

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Makefile build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make",
            "args": [],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/SRC"
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

launch.json:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug (MacOS)",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/SRC/main",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/SRC/",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "targetArchitecture": "arm64",
            "preLaunchTask": "Makefile build",
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: what version of VS Code and the C++ extension did you have when you were able to reproduce this problem?

Comment: @user for VSC, it was 1.77. For the C++ extension, I have no idea on how to see this, and if it has been updated recently. What I can say is that the bug was still present last week when I tested it, and wasn't present this morning.

Comment: you can check the version in the extensions view. Open it, scroll to the C++ extensions, and hover your mouse over it. the hover info will say what version is installed. You can try and older version by clicking "Install Another Version..." in the gear icon menu. I think future readers would really appreciate it if you go an extra mile to narrow down where the problem is coming from.

Comment: I'm using version v1.15.4. I tried with a version that's two month old, it did stop at breakpoint. So it must be the VSCode update that fixed something somewhere somehow...

Comment: which version specifically did you try that worked?

Comment: It was version 1.14.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSCode was updated recently ([1.78](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates)), and the problem disappeared. So I presume it was a bug withing the software.

Comment: are you sure it's not an update that happened to the C++ extension coincidentally near the same time?

Comment: @user it might be, yeah, good point. But I don't really care as long as it works ! ;)

Comment: :| this is how DenverCoder09 situations are born.

Comment: Who's DenverCoder09 ?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: Ok I get it, but I do think that my answer is sufficient for someone to understand that they would have to update their VSCode/C++ extension if they see an available update