# VSCode debugger not stopping at breakpoint (with -g already set)

Tags: c, gdb

I am on Visual Studio Code 1.84.2.
For an odd reason why I set a breakpoint, build, then debug I notice my breakpoints get cleared out and the following error over them: `Module containing this breakpoint has not yet loaded or the breakpoint address could not be obtained.`

Here is my launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "C/C++ Debug Current File",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": true,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

tasks.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "C/C++: Compile Current File",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "gcc",
      "args": [
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe", // Specify the output file with .exe extension
        "-lws2_32"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}" // Set the working directory
      },
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "shared"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If it also helps, my c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
  "configurations": [
      {
          "name": "Win32",
          "includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/**"],
          "defines": ["_DEBUG", "UNICODE", "_UNICODE"],
          "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
          "cStandard": "c17",
          "cppStandard": "c++17",
          "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
          "browse": {
              "path": ["${workspaceFolder}"],
              "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
              "databaseFilename": ""
          }
      }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

I have already saw this thread: [VSCode debugger not stopping at breakpoint (with -g compilation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76013825/vscode-debugger-not-stopping-at-breakpoint-with-g-compilation) . However, I am on the lastest visual studio code. I don't get why my debugger is not stopping at the breakpoint.

Comment: Is your breakpoint in a shared library that is only loaded later within the program execution?  The error would seem to indicate this might be the case.  Can you run to a time when the shared library is loaded, and then create the breakpoint?

Comment: I removed the"-lws2_32" and tested it on a simple helloworld program, but VSCode still does not hit any breakpoints when I set them